# Show percent of image based on database

Tags: jquery, css

Ive tried looking for a solution but im unsure of exactly what the term would be called. I am looking for jquery ajax call to a MySQL database to determine a number (0-100%) and use that number as a percentage. Use that percentage to produce a live(checked every 1 minute) indication of what the percent is.

So imagine an image of an empty glass of water, every 60 seconds a call to MySQL is performed and the percent number is retrieved from MySQL. That number is what will make the background image display starting from the bottom. Every 60 seconds when that number gets bigger from MySQL more of the image is displayed until the glass is 100% full.

I can handle all the MySQL queries and php that needs to be done, i just dont know if there is a term for this style animation or a plugin or what exactly im looking for to make the image 'roll up' every 60 seconds based on the returned value from MySQL

What i am using with success:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        setInterval(function() {
            var a = $('#inner').height();

            $('#inner').animate({ height: a + 25 });
        }, 3000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outter">
        <div id="inner" style="background-color:blue; height:0px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe6Ks/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) property:

```
var target = document.getElementById('target'),
    h = target.clientHeight,
    w = target.clientWidth;
setInterval(function(){
    var v = h*(1-getPercentage()/100) | 0;
    target.style.clip = 'rect('+v+'px,'+w+'px,'+h+'px,0)';
}, 100);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGpFf/)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way - create an image which has a transparent area representing actual empty glass. Position it (or whatever element uses it as a background) on top of a DIV with blue background. And simple control that background DIV height based on number you return from your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the jquery animate function to increase the hight of the coloured section and call it every 60 seconds using the setInterval function (although it should be noted that this is not precise for exact timings).

Something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.post("url", function(data) { 
        $("#image").animate({"height": data + "px"});
    }
}, 60000);
```

With the #image increasing in height placed behind a static "glass" image.

E.G.:

```
HTML:
<div id="image-container">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <img src="glass.png" />
</div>
```